# How to hide blank divs when page loads

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, html-table

I am using script below to hide the blank `div` , `li`, and `td`. It's working fine.
The only issue I am facing is, when the page loads it shows the blank `divs`, `li` and `td`. 
I have a border class on these blank divs which get visible till the page loading gets complete which I don't want. I want to keep it hidden until these elements are not filled with any text or any content.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:empty").css('display', 'none');
    $("div[class='errorMsg']").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;}).css('display', 'none');
    $('li').filter(function(){return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';}).hide()
    $("td[class='noShow']").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;}).css('display', 'none');
  });
```

Can I get any help to make it fix.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple solution is to change your strategy . By default keep divs hidden and display those divs that are not blank .

*update :*

in your css file hide div.errorMsg :

```
div.errorMsg
{
    display : none;
}
```

then in your script just modify your code as below:

```
$("div[class='errorMsg']").filter(function(i,v){return $.trim($(v).text()).length > 0;}).css('display', 'block');
```

or write it as below :

```
$("div.errorMsg:not(:empty)").css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Hey, i also got that idea. But saw yours after my edit posted

Answer (score 1):

Why not this way:

```
var $div2hide = $.trim($("div.errorMsg:empty"));
$div2hide.hide();
```

Just get the empty div and trim any whitespace it has and if it is empty then just hide it.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide `empty` divs with specific class `errorMsg` on page load like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.errorMsg:empty").hide();
});
```

If you want to hide all the `empty` divs on the page:

```
$(function() {
    $("div:empty").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify dom before it loaded. But if you really want to do it then take this apporch:

- by default hide every `div`, `li` etc.
- when the document get ready display them if they are not empty

Answer (score 0):

Basically we use this if an element is empty to hide

```
$(function() {
      $("element:empty").hide();
});
```